# I have a countdown, but it seems to be affected by local timezone, how do I transform this into a universal timezone countdown?

Tags: javascript, countdown

```
    // Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("July 26, 2022 19:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownfunction);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Refresh the page! Ctrl+F5";
  }
}, 1000);
```

This is my current javascript, but it shows a differnt end date regarding on which timezone their computer is currently set to, is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone/15171030#15171030
Does this help you?

Comment: Well `new Date("July 26, 2022 19:00:00")` doesn't have a timezone specified, so it will assume the system one. Write `new Date("2022-07-26T19:00:00Z")` instead